# need recommendation for a book questions / answers

Tags: c#, javascript

I need a programming book with questions and answers, doesn't matter what programming language it uses in examples as long it is C based language (preferably C# or JavaScript). What important is that questions in this book will be high degree programming (ie. create a function that will check 4 in row following numbers in 2D array)...

Basically questions you get in computer science degree tests and most important answers...

I feel i miss a lot because i haven't done my degree, so i want to learn basic programming, stuff like loops, if conditions, lists and recursions. I know how these can be used for years but i want complex problems with solutions so i can force my brain to try and then read how writer solved it.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ for some challenging puzzles.

Comment: Just buy any Advanced `insert programming language here` book

Comment: @minitech, thanks but i want a book to do it in my time, without others.

Comment: The [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems are awesome for the kind of thing you're thinking about, plus they're a great way to learn a little bit about number theory (and algorithm design, and data structure efficiency, and a lot of other things too).

Comment: @KevinDTimm, can you recommend me any book in this genre?

Comment: Why pointless votes for closing? I want to buy a book and there is no questions like this so i couldn't learn.

Comment: @eugeneK - no recommendations off the top of my head, I just peruse the books at the local bookstore - even Half Price Books is good for this, 2 year old technology isn't too old for advanced learning ;)

Comment: @KevinDTimm, i don't mind these books being from 1970 as long as they will teach me creative problem solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing about questions like "create a function that will check 4 in row following numbers in 2D array" is the algorithm that solve the problem not the programming language.

So,I suggest you to read [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937),[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) written by [Prof. H. Cormen](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/) this book will gave you a great skill to solved mentioned type problems.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of books i was looking for...

Comment: I prefer using native to me language to write algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate question...?

See :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-net-books
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795/recommended-books-for-learning-c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-c

Comment: I've asked for books with questions and answers for algorithmic problems ( using two languages i know the best C# and JS) not for a book to learn C#.

Comment: @eugeneK Ok, I didn't understood your question like you want specifically Q&A for algo problems, my mistake :)